# What is normally used in XNA?

Tags: c#, xna, blender, 3dsmax, fbx

I'm following a course in XNA (yes I know it's almost outdated). My teacher said something about multiple 3D-objects in your world just by importing one FBX file.

So is it recommended to create your complete game world in just one FBX file, or is it more common to create all the separate objects and program them manually to be somewhere in space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely keep your models in separate files. Sometimes it's even recommended to have a single model made up of several files, if it's a large model. Obviously still having the origin in the same place, so when you spawn the 2 models on the same coordinates, it will fit nicely.

Such cases may be, but are not limited to, castles, mountains, trees, graveyards, churches, walls, etc.

Keeping models in separate files gives a lot of advantages such as faster loading, option for loading fewer models (not loading models that are out of line of sight, etc.

Also, if you were to have your entire world in 1 file, first of all you'd have everything loaded into a single model, second of all, the texture for the world would be a nightmare, and MANY megabytes large, and in general it would be a complete nightmare to keep track of everything.

Comment: hahah i think you've made your statement clear! Thanks for explaining :)!

Comment: You're welcome. This same thing also goes for items and other sort of data objects. Keep them in separate files, otherwise it'll get cluttered, and will also take longer to load :)